# using requestanimationframe, profiling shows >80% time spent idle, still getting 4fps. why? (/how to fix?)

Tags: javascript, android, performance, google-chrome, canvas

I have a simple canvas game. It's architected with a simple `requestAnimationFrame` loop that updates the state, and then renders to the canvas (simple!). It runs really well on desktop + iOS, but on chrome on android, it runs terribly.

Here's the loop, for example:

```
var tick = function()
{
  requestAnimationFrame(tick,canvas);
  cur_scene.tick();
  cur_scene.draw();
}
```

So I pulled up the remote profiler, recorded a quick session, and over (any given) 1 second, it shows ~.82s idle (.11s scripting, .04s 'other', .02 painting, .005 rendering).

It also shows ~.1s per frame (the space between consecutive `Animation Frame Fired` entries on the flame graph). But the flame graph is like (consistent with the other measurements) 80% empty?

So I'm at a loss- what can I do to get this to render at a higher framerate? Am I reading the diagnostic info incorrectly? Have I structured the requestAnimationFrame loop incorrectly?

Edit: Here's an annotated picture of some of the performance diagnostics (picked up by recording a remote session on my android phone)
[image: perf]

Comment: That's kind of hard for us to tell for sure... We've got neither your actual code, neither your actual device. Btw, have you tried on different devices? Did you tried on different browsers on the same device? As for the structure of your anim loop... yes, sounds correct, even though rAF accepts only a single param (`canvas` gets lost here). Now, it all depends what happens in tick and draw.

Comment: The problem is that "my actual code" doesn't seem to be running slowly at all (unless I'm misunderstanding the diagnostics). Here's an annotated screenshot: http://phildogames.com/scratch/perf.png . My "tick" and "draw" code is circled. It appears there's something about "requestAnimationFrame" that's just idling between frames for ~5x what it takes to do any computation.
For your other questions- yes, it performs badly on all android+chrome devices I've tried. Performs great on everything else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to put the call to requestAnimationFrame() at the end of your method like this:

```
var tick = function()
{
  cur_scene.tick();
  cur_scene.draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(tick,canvas);
}
```

Else you might end up entering the loop again without drawing anything but requesting the animation frame again.
When you check the following example, they also first do their changes to the object before they call requestAnimationFrame():
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

The above documentation explains this in the following text:

> The method takes a callback as an argument to be invoked before the repaint. [...] You should call this method whenever you're ready to update your animation onscreen.